# Symfony 4: Where is the logic of the CollectionType's "allow_delete" option?

Tags: forms, symfony4

So, I'm trying to understand Symfony forms. I'm searching the core code for "allow_delete" option to see how it works under the hood, but the only place where it can be found is in the `CollectionType` class and I cannot find any logic there.

Documentation [states](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-delete):

> If set to true, then if an existing item is not contained in the
>   submitted data, it will be correctly absent from the final array of
>   items.

Where in the code exactly it influences the submitted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the function in `MergeCollectionListener.php` beginning on line 91:

```
// Remove deleted items before adding to free keys that are to be
// replaced
if ($this->allowDelete) {
        foreach ($itemsToDelete as $key) {
            unset($dataToMergeInto[$key]);
        }
    }
```

`$dataToMergeInto` is set as `$dataToMergeInto = $event->getForm()->getNormData();`
 which refers to a function in which is explained in `FormInterface.php`:

```
/**
 * Returns the normalized data of the field.
 *
 * @return mixed When the field is not submitted, the default data is returned.
 *               When the field is submitted, the normalized submitted data is
 *               returned if the field is valid, null otherwise.
 */
public function getNormData();
```